# GLib custom event source masking

Tags: c, glib

**Context:**
I created my custom event sources as described in [this guide](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/custom-gsource.c.html.en). 
My simplified code:

```
#define DEFAULT_POLL_TIMEOUT    100

typedef struct{
    GSource source;
    std::string file_path;
}FileObserverSource;

static GSourceFuncs fobserver_source_funcs{
    FobserverPrepare,
    NULL,  /* check */
    FobserverDispatch,
    FobserverFinalize
};

GSource *FOBS_ObserverConstruct(std::string file_path, GSourceFunc callback){
    GSource *source=g_source_new(&fobserver_source_funcs, sizeof(FileObserverSource));
    FileObserverSource *fobserver_source=(FileObserverSource *)source;
    fobserver_source->file_path=file_path;
    g_source_set_callback(source,callback,NULL,NULL);
    return source;
}

static gboolean FobserverPrepare(GSource *source, gint *timeout_){
    gboolean ret=false;
    FileObserverSource *fobserver_source=(FileObserverSource *)source;
    if(FOBS_ScanForFile(fobserver_source->file_path.c_str())){
        ret=true;
    }
    if(!ret){
        *timeout_=DEFAULT_POLL_TIMEOUT;
    }
    return ret;
}

static gboolean FobserverDispatch (GSource *source, GSourceFunc callback,gpointer user_data){
    FileObserverSource *fobserver_source=(FileObserverSource *)source;
    callback((gpointer)fobserver_source->file_path.c_str());
    return TRUE;
}

static void FobserverFinalize (GSource *source){
}

int main(void){
    GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new( NULL , FALSE );
    GMainContext *main_context=g_main_loop_get_context(loop);
    g_source_attach(FOBS_ObserverConstruct(ws_file_path,ProcessCMDFile),main_context); 
    g_main_loop_run(loop);
}
```

**Problem:** Now I want to temporary turn off continuous source checks depends on some program internal states.

Does glib provides api for masking event sources? 
Is it possible or i need to delete/recreate sources or implement custom source management logic by myself (for example set flag in my code and check this flag in prepare function)?

As I read in documentation g_source_destroy() destroy source and i can't reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Without example code it’s hard to tell exactly what your setup is.

However, in general:

- If you have written your own `GSource` implementation, you should disable it by returning `FALSE` from [its `check` function](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFuncs).
- If you are using a pre-existing `GSource` implementation, you should disable it by returning from its callback function early.

  - [Removing](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-destroy) and [re-adding](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-attach) the source is a lot more expensive. You can do this if you want to disable it for a long period of time, but don’t do it if you’re only going to disable the source for one or two callbacks.

Comment: I added code example and clarified my problem. If i return FALSE in dispatch function source wouldn't be checked more. But i need to turn it off temporary.

Comment: Add an implementation of `GSourceFuncs.check` and return `FALSE` from that when (and only when) you want the source to be disabled.

Comment: Presumably using `check` means it is polled on every iteration of the loop. An alternative way of switching GSources on and off could be to toggle `g_source_set_ready_time` to 0 for on and -1 for off. That's my understanding of [Bug 744441 - RFE: Add g_condition_source() ](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744441)

Comment: Yes, using `check` means it is polled on every iteration of the loop. The `GSource`’s `ready_time` is also checked on every iteration of the loop. You can use `g_source_set_ready_time()` to ensure the main context wakes up at the time when you think your `GSource` will return `TRUE` from `check()` again, but you can’t just use ready times on their own — they have to be used in conjunction with a `prepare` or `check` function which always returns the appropriate state for the `GSource`.